# Event handlers for Twitter Bootstrap drop downs sent value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tell me how to pass the value selected from a list box

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var selected = $(this).text();
  $('.category').val(selected);  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-7 pull-right well">
      <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="get">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="q">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" id="action-1">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="action-1">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="action-1">3</a></li>
        </ul>
         <input type="hidden" name="category" class="category">
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Admissible in the pop-up window I choose "1" to pass to the class = "form-control" value = "1"

Here is example code:
http://bootply.com/93417

Comment: what is the problem? do you want to pass it to the searchbox?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass value to search box

Comment: like this http://bootply.com/98806

Comment: You almost had it, just change .category to .box in your script and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks, all done. Is very simply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have puts the value in a hidden text box called category. If you wish to have it in the search field add a new class (in this case i've added `box`) to its class attribute and call that in your script:

link: http://bootply.com/98806

like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-7 pull-right well">
  <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="get">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-8">
      <input class="form-control box" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="q">
   <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
     <input type="hidden" name="category" class="category">
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and change your script accordingly

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var selected = $(this).text();
   $('.box').val(selected);
});
```